# Can phone gap HTML apps establish sessions with a asp.net Mvc web server

Tags: ios, asp.net-mvc, cordova, jquery-mobile

Or do you need to use a sessionless system I.e web service requests with an authorisation token in every request?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how are you going to create an application. Nothing can prevent you from doing that. Instead of using your files in phonegap www dir you can reference loadUrl to a remote web server, thus sessions will work. And here's an example:

Phonegap + Android :

In your main activity class, method **onCreate** change **loadUrl** to:

**super.loadUrl("http://.../index.html");**

iPhone + Phonegap ia another story, still it can be done. Because there are a lot of changes here's a tutorial: http://www.joeldare.com/wiki/open_a_url_in_phonegap

One more thing, you must enable an internet connection for the Phonegap.

As you are using the android platform add this line to your AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

A viewport meta tag must be set in your html file.

One more thing, if you are creating a iOS app there's a good chance you app will be published because of my first solution. In that case you need to handle it with some kind of web service requests.